# How to select the first (second, ...) non empty element in an excel list?

Tags: excel

In an excel sheet (Office Professional Plus 2016) I have an empty 'A' column with the exception of the cells A4, A5, A7 and A9 which contain some text. I now want to extract the first non-empty element (which is located in call A4). I found the following suggestion (from [here](http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/01/15/find-first-non-blank-item-in-a-list-excel-formulas/) and [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-first-non-blank-value-in-a-list)) and I am using the following expression in some other cell (outside column `A`):

```
=INDEX(A1:A9;MATCH(FALSE;ISBLANK(A1:A9);0))
```

but this only gives ma a `#N/A`. Maybe the formula does not with anymore in the newer version of Office? Or what could the reason of the error be?

And how do I select the second non-empty element (from cell A5) and the third non-empty element (Cell A7) and so on...?

To further clarify; I want to fill column B with the non-empty elements of column A. So B1 should contain the first non-empty element of column A (which is Cell A4); B2 should contain the second non-empty element of column A (which is Cell A5); B2 should contain the third non-empty element of column A (which is Cell A7);  and so on ...

Comment: This is an array formula. So instead of hitting `Enter` after writing the formula you are supposed to press  `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` together.

Comment: Yes, thanks, and I should really start to read.... This is explained on the pages...

Comment: But how to find the second non-empty cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the following formula in a cell and drag it down. This will give you all non-empty cells

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$9,SMALL(INDEX(NOT(ISBLANK($A$1:$A$9))*ROW($A$1:$A$9),0),COUNTBLANK($A$1:$A$9)+ROW(A1))),"")
```

This is an array formula so commit it by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Change your range as required.

Comment: It gives me the FIRST non-empty element. How to get the second non-empty element?

Comment: @Alex Mrig's formula does what you are asking. You need to press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter` and then drag the formula down.

Comment: @Alex - copy this formula down.