# How to get the row number of the first (second, ...) non-empty element in an excel list?

Tags: excel

This question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411094/how-to-select-the-first-second-non-empty-element-in-an-excel-list), but instead a certain element I want to have the row-number of the corresponding element.

In an excel sheet (Office Professional Plus 2016) I have an empty 'A' column with the exception of the cells A4, A5, A7 and A9 which contain some text. I now want to fill column B with the row-numbers of these rows of columns A which are not empty. So B1 should contain the value '4', B2 should contain the value '5', B3 should contain the value '7' and so on...

Answer (score 1):

As it took too long to wait for an answer I tried myself and I think the correct answer is as follows:

```
=IFERROR(ROW(INDEX($A$1:$A$9,SMALL(INDEX(NOT(ISBLANK($A$1:$A$9))*ROW($A$1:$A$9),0),COUNTBLANK($A$1:$A$9)+ROW(A1)))),"")
```

Comment: Now this is called Perfection :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another formula to get row numbers of non-blank cells.

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF($A1:$A9<>"",ROW($A1:$A9)),ROW(1:1)),"")
```

This is also an array formula so needs to be committed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.